# xtext check annotation issue

Tags: annotations, xtext

I'm using the @Check annotation in order to validate my dsl. my dsl is for json.

at first the method was invoked for a specific object and once per change
but it suddenly doesn't work in the same way anymore (and i'm not sure what i've done that effected it)
the method signature is:

```
@Check 
public void validateJson(ObjectValue object) {...}
```

now its entering this method for each node in the gui although i'm editing only one node

Answer (score 0):

The validator works normally in this case. When Xtext re-parses your model, it cannot always avoid re-creating the EMF model that is validated in the Check expression - in other words, the model is practically re-created every time, thus warranting a full validation.

However, in some cases, it is possible that only a partial re-creation of the model is necessary - in these cases it is possible that not all elements are re-validated (however, I am not sure whether this optimization was included).

Comment: thanks, Do you know how can i control it? i want it to be as optimize as possible

Comment: I know only a single way about controlling the execution: the annotation has an optional attribute whether it is fast, normal or expensive. If I recall correctly, expensive rules are only validated manually, normal on each save, while fast on-the-fly. Of course I know that is not what you want, but the declarative validator does not support anything else. (AFAIK).

Comment: thanks, but how come it was fine before? what can cause this kind of change?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know. Maybe you could use the debugger and look at from where is the validator called, but I have no more concrete ideas.